# How do I punctuate a sentence which describes a product or item?

Tags: punctuation

How do I punctuate a sentence which describes a product or item?

***Example -***
Radiant; De Beers: South African sourced, alluvial diamonds.

Is there a hard and fast rule regarding how this sentence should be composed? Am I using unnecessary punctuation?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example isn't a complete sentence.  It looks more like an entry in an index or dictionary.  I assume it means something like "Radiant, as used by the company DeBeers, refers to an alluvial diamond sourced from South Africa."  If I'm correct in my interpretation, then I don't believe there are "hard and fast rules" for punctuation.  Most dictionaries and similar works have style guides that dictate the rules they use.  If you're not creating entries for an established work, you could still look at similar works and adapt one of their style guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[De Beers's Radiant, South-African-sourced, alluvial diamond.]

[Radiant, South-African-sourced, alluvial De Beers diamond.]